# Mezzanine with grappelli (default) admin theme

Tags: django, django-grappelli, mezzanine

I have just started my project using Mezzanine (The django CMS framework)

but I can't get the grappelli theme to work?

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd think it may have something do do with the way the grappelli admin files are being served. how are you serving them? what do you see now- standard admin or something that is clearly missing css/images?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't mentioned how you're hosting the app.

If you're using Apache or NGINX you'll need to add the correct aliases to your web server's configuration file as described here: http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/deployment.html

If you're using Django's built-in development server, Mezzanine will use the IP address you bind it to to host Grappelli's static files. It might be that you're binding to 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 and trying to access the site from another machine on the local network, so those IP addresses won't resolve correctly.

These are the two most common problems. If this doesn't help you'll need to provide more info.

Update 16 March 2012: Mezzanine 1.0 exclusively uses Django's staticfiles app, so no special handling is required other than what staticfiles dictates.